# Not able to install npm, getting module.js error which doing FCC node.js challenge

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloud9-ide

```
   module.js:471
        throw err;
        ^
  Error: Cannot find module 'process-nextick-args'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:26:23)
        at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    Uh oh!  npm had a problem! { Error: Command failed: "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/bin/npm" --version
    module.js:471
        throw err;
```

Trying to do FCC first challenge of node.js but stuck at installing and verifying npm. tried to google the error to debug it but found only questions no answer to it! could anybody help?

Comment: Try installing a different version of the package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug on npm. I recommend to update Node.js and npm.

Run following commands on console:

```
$ nvm install 6 # This installs Node.js version 6.11.3, current latest version of Node.js 6.x
$ npm install --global npm # Install latest version of npm
```

[I found this issue happen on other learners of Free Code Camp](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/npm-cannot-find-module-process-nextick-args/145424/3)

Comment: great! thanks it worked. I updated node.js and npm both :)